# Permissão Facebook Developer

Tags: facebook

É possível através das permissões do *facebook* eu poder ler, incluir e alterar informações no perfil do usuário utilizando o meu App externo?

Exemplo: Caso eu queira incluir uma foto ou alterar as conversas do chat desse usuário!